# Launch camera to take photo in countdown mode

Tags: android

How can I launch to the device camera, in built-in countdown mode, configure it to 10s and take a photo?
Without user interaction.
The user should not press the capture button. It should start programmatically.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, the "device camera" does not necessarily have a "built-in countdown mode". There are thousands of Android device models, with dozens (if not hundreds) of pre-installed camera apps. None have to have this feature. Similarly, there are hundreds of camera apps available on the Play Store, and none of them have to have this feature.

Second, even if a camera app has this feature, there is no requirement that it expose an API for third-party developers to invoke this feature.

Third, even if a camera app has this feature and exposes an API for it, there is no standards for this API.

You are welcome to contact the developers of various camera apps and see if they have the feature and, if so, if they have an API for third-party developers to invoke it.

Comment: Thanks. According to your answer, I'd developed my own module using android camera API and capture image after countdown.